# Syntax error near "," Updating database rows

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently having an issue with my program.

I am trying to update an accrued interest amount to a table within SQL however I get the error

> SQL logic error near ",": syntax error

I have already tried to rewrite this as selecting from the database then updating but this seems to work the easiest

```
string newaccrude =
    @"UPDATE account, product SET accrued = accrued + (balance * intrate)/365.0";

cmd = con.CreateCommand();
con.Open();
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(newaccrude, con);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The accrued interest should be the sum of the calculation within the code and each row within the accrued column should be updated with the new values

Tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product  
(
    prodid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    isaname TEXT,
    status TEXT,
    transin INTEGER,
    intrate REAL
);

CREATE TABLE account 
(
    accid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    custid INTEGER,
    prodid INTEGER,
    balance REAL,
    accrued REAL,
    active TEXT,

    FOREIGN KEY (custid) REFERENCES customer (custid),
    FOREIGN KEY (prodid) REFERENCES product (prodid)
);
```

Comment: You can only specify one table after `UPDATE`.

Comment: so how would i update the table then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all: you're not supposed to put a comma at this place.

With the table definition you shared, I would do:

```
UPDATE account
SET accrued = accrued +
    (SELECT account.balance*intrate/365 FROM product WHERE product.prodid = account.prodid)
```